# How to read Excel file in Android Studio from the assets folder

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to make an Android application that reads data from an Excel file added as an asset. But I believe that some Apache POI function won't work. I got the code from https://www.blueappsoftware.com/how-to-read-excel-file-in-android-tutorial/

I am using Android Studio and Java as a programming language. I know that in order to create a workbook using the Apache POI library I need to have an existing (in my case XLSX) Excel file (that I added to as an asset to my application). And I know that the assets folder holds merely zip files of the file I want to read. So I need to 'convert' the xlsx file in my asset folder to a file. Any ideas?

```
        //inside my Onclick function
        InputStream in;
        AssetManager assetManager=getApplicationContext().getAssets();
        in=assetManager.open("cableSizing.xlsx");
        POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(in);
        //create the workbook
        Workbook workbook= WorkbookFactory.create(myFileSystem);
```

Error stacktrace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.michel.cablesizing, PID: 19029
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
 Caused by: org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:126)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:113)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:301)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:81)
    at com.example.michel.cablesizing.MainActivity.TakeActionOK(MainActivity.java:40)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: jxl library can be used for this purpose.

Comment: Just pass the stream straight to `WorkbookFactory` and let it detect the type for you as intended?

Answer (score 0):

i noticed that POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(in) supports only .xls files not xlsx. i changed it to .xls and everything worked fine. but anybody knows what works for .xlsx files?